# Controlling inner diameter, outer diameter, and height of object using geometry nodes

Tags: 3d-printing, geometry-nodes

I can create / adjust the size of a torus created using Geometry Nodes but the changes are affecting the entire object in more than one axis / settings.  `Example of an issue, if I change the outer radius the inner radius also changes` see animation below.

Node Setup:
[image: img1]

Example:

- I'm trying to have the outer radius only affect the outer radius.
- I'm trying to have the inner radius only affect the inner radius.
- I'm trying to have the height only affect the height of the object so if I type in 2.4mm the height will be a a total of 2.4mm from top to bottom.

I know this can be done with the torus object but the goal is to use Geometry Nodes to learn it.

Issues.

[image: img2]

This will be used to create custom 3D printed washers and o-rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *Add* > *Mesh* > *Torus* context menu you can originally switch between the "Major/Minor" method or the "Exterior/Interior" method to create the torus.

With the following *Geometry Nodes* nodetree you can choose between those two methods as well: it has a boolean input to select which method you want. 0 (False) means "Major/Minor" whereas 1 (True) means "Exterior/Interior" method.

The other inputs define the major and minor radii resp. exterior and interior radii according to the chosen method.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot you want to control the height as well and added it.

[image: torus creation]

**EDIT 2:** Before it gets too boring you can add more nodes and a boolean input to decide whether you want a washer with a circular / ellipsoid profile or a flat washer:

[image: torus creation 2]

Answer (score 8):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without dividing the input values by 2 you should call them outer and inner diameter instead of radius.